# Function to extract API queries results and output them as list or dictionary

Tags: python, function, for-loop, data-science, gqlquery

I need a list of the results of an API call using gql for a dictionary of IDs. Let's say I have a dictionary of locations, ex: `{"tokyo": "111", "rio": "112", "LA": "113"}`, and I need to query on an API the info for each location, ex:

```
    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url=API_URL, headers=HEADERS)
    client = Client(transport=transport)
    params = {
        "id": "111"
        "time": {"from": "2022-05-10", "to": "2022-05-19"},
        }
    q = gql(query)
    r = client.execute(q, variable_values=params)
    pprint.pprint(r)
```

I am trying to design a function that extracts the results of the queries for each ID at once and outputs it as a list. However I am new to python and I am unsure of how to go about it. I started with a function and a for loop, something like this:

```
total = []

def get_info(dictionary_location):
  for key, value in dictionary_location.items():  
    global params
       params = {
       "lineId": value,
       "time": {"from": "2022-05-10", "to": "2022-05-19"}
       }
        q = gql(query)
        r = client.execute(q, variable_values = params)
return total.append(r)
```

But it's not working. Does anyone have an input on the logic/syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. The main one is that because you are returning `total.append(r)` within the loop, then only the first iteration of the loop is done. Make these changes into your code:

```py
def get_info(dictionary_location):
    total = []
    for value in dictionary_location.values():  
        params = {
                  "lineId": value,
                  "time": {"from": "2022-05-10", "to": "2022-05-19"}
                  }
        q = gql(query)
        r = client.execute(q, variable_values = params)
        total.append(r)

    return total
```

In this way you will:

1. instantiate an empty list `total`
2. loop over each location item, it looks like you don't need the `key` param so I removed it
3. append the results of the `query` to the `total` list
4. repeat until done
5. once all the items have been iterated, then return the list containing the results of the `query`